# ThreadPoolExecutor and main thread executing concurrently in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to understand Python's ThreadPoolExecutor a bit better and am trying to figure out if there is any difference in running all computation under a ThreadPoolExecutor vs running some in the main thread.

For example:

```
from concurrent import futures


def fn1():
  while True:
    ...


def _fn2():
  ...


def fn2():
  while True:
    _fn2()
```

Is there a difference between:

```
executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
for completed in futures.as_completed(
    [executor.submit(fn1), executor.submit(fn2)]):
  completed.result()
```

vs

```
executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
future_fn1 = executor.submit(fn1)

# Simulate fn in main thread, but with check on future_fn1.
while True:
  _fn2()
  if future_fn1.done():
    future_fn1.result()
```

What are the main differences between the two approaches? Should I expect a big performance difference - e.g. threads being more efficiently managed if the executor is used for both?

Comment: Re, "threads being more efficiently managed..." I don't actually know the details of Python's ThreadPoolExecutor, but I would be very surprised if it did any kind of "management" for a thread that actually was executing a task. In _general_ (including, in other languages) the only management that a thread pool does is deciding whether to spin up more threads when demand is high, deciding whether to kill off idle threads when demand is low, handling shutdown requests, dealing with tasks that throw exceptions, completing futures... Stuff that happens before or after tasks get run.

Comment: P.S., If you are asking whether there's any difference between doing work on the main thread vs. doing work in some other thread, then the answer _probably_ is "no difference." (But again, I'm not really an expert.)

Comment: Thanks Solomon! I think I share your intuition here, but am hoping to get it confirmed. I wouldn't be surprised to see that handling the "main thread" with the executor improves resource management, but I also don't have the low-level understanding of Python threading to support this.